# What is the best way to store double dimension vector in c++?

Tags: c++

What is the best way to store double dimension vector in c++?

```
std::vector <std::vector <int> > m_vector(N, std::vector<int>(M));
...
int k = m_vector[i][j];
```

How else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient and most convenient at the same time is to use [`boost::multi_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is the BKM (Best known method). It's the most straight forward and it does what you need, with easy access using the [][] operator.
You can always use set<> or list<> if you don't need vector's extra functionality...